# How to get just the value from dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working on an already working code, and when i do this print statement, `print(transaction_obj["group"])` i get

```
Transaction: 83a9bb1f808c464fbf21952abbfd8c0a
```

not sure if it's a dict, i just want to get `83a9bb1f808c464fbf21952abbfd8c0a` this value when i print. I tried to print just the value by `transaction_obj["group"][0]` and `transaction_obj["group"]['Transaction']`, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Maybe it's just a string ? try `type(transaction_obj["group"])` to see the type of the object that you are getting.

Comment: You better try to print the type by `print(type(transaction_obj["group"]))` to see the type. It can be a string as well, if it is a string you may get the value you want by splitting.

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work": how do you know it doesn't work? Be detailed. [edit] the question.

Answer (score 1):

There could be different ways.

In Python you need to know the output type.

If this is a string, you can either:

```
output = string.split(':')[-1].lstrip()
#or 
output = string.split(': ')[-1]

#performance: 93.8 ns ± 1.54 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
```

if, and only if you guarantee that structure: `Transaction: SPACE YOUR_DESIRED_RESULT`

Or you can use regex

```
import re 
output = re.search(': (.+?)$',string).group(1)
#performance: 611 ns ± 9.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to check the type of value you want by using

```
print(type(transaction_obj["group"]))
```

If it is a string(most probably it is), you may use [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) function in order to split the second part from the string by

```
print(transaction_obj["group"].split()[1])
```